Electric Vehicles Domain: Ongoing and New Analytics Research Problems
The purpose of this question is to summarize list of open/ongoing analytics research opportunities due to advent of Electric Vehicles. I get lots of queries from folks asking if there are any good problems to work on, and also if there are any good sources of sample data on which one can validate their models. Some of the current EV publications can be accessed here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/search?qs=electric%20vehicle

Few aspects I have thought are listed here. I welcome everyone else to enrich this further.


What is so different than ICE (Internal Combustion Engine)?
EV’s are fundamentally different
1. Digital by design
2. Key to “connected” and “automated” mobility
3. Battery (unlike petrol/diesel) charges from a “shared” and “tough to store” resource
Multiple stakeholders. Example: Problem to decide charger location reuires thinking of:

EV Owners: Maximize coverage (by population)
Government: Maximize coverage (by area)
Operator: Maximize revenue
DISCOM (Power Supplier): Maximize usage

Unlike ICE vehicles, the ecosystem is not stable. It will take several years and many new interventions/innovations in technology, policies, and our mindset for it to happen.
What data one will be looking at?

Battery state of charge
Battery performance (charge/discharge rate, ambient temperature)
Battery state of health
EV ownership (make, model, location)
EV usage (schedule, duration, distance, location)
EV charging (home, office, pubic, charging schedule, charging power level, charging duration)
EV chargers (locations, power, tariff)
EV charger operations (usage, diagnostics data, maintenance, smart features)
Demographics (purchase capacity, vehicle usage, etc)
Real-estate data (space usage/availability, parking availability, rent/purchase prices)
Electricity network (sub-transformer capacity, access/distance to high power)
Electricity demand (demand from industry/residential, peaks, rates)
Policies (rules/regulations incentives provided by government/industry)
Exogenous factors (economy, business environment, funding)

Analytics in EV Battery Charging
State of Charge Determination

How much is the battery currently charged?

Charging/Discharging Prediction

Type of battery (chemistry etc)
Recent performance
Ambient temperature
Expected usage conditions

BMS (Battery Management System) Optimization

Battery Management System
Optimal balancing of cells
Optimal cooling/heating

Analytics in EV Battery Supply/Demand
Predict demand and supply

Based on the market data, current R&D progress etc, predict how much battery production capacity will be needed

Battery Recycling

Second life, reuse, cyclic economy, urban mining
Designing the supply chain for recycling
Note: Second life also determines the rasale value of the EV

Analytics in EV Chargepoint Operations
Capacity planning

Where to place the chargers, how many, what type?
What policy to use for smart charging?
Automatic suggestions to relocate chargers to location with higher usage.

Reservation modeling

How to support remote reservation?

Maintenance planning

Predict and plan maintenance required for the charger (time-based -> condition-based or risk-based)
Predict abnormal behavior, theft

Behavioral

How will we ensure that EV owners make the EV charging parking spot available after car is charged?

Analytics in EV Electricity Supply
Load Planning

Predicting the electricity infrastructure requirement for next year, next decade?
Predicting the electricity demands for next hour, day, week?

V2G (Vehicle-to-Grid)

EV will become a local power resource too. How will we manage supply/demand at such a large scale?

Behavioral

Running programs like Time-of-Use (TOU) to reduce peak load. Determine when to have higher and lower charging cost?
How will we ensure that EV owners charge their car during off-peak hours?
What reward (monetary and/or social) should be there? Shall we use model like reinforcement learning be relevant here?

Analytics for EV Fleet Operators
Real-time status

Battery current charge status
Battery remaining kms prediction

Real-time routing

Navigation to suggest next feasible charging point

Fleet assignment

Assign the fleet to the routes based on their current charging status
Determine the right charging schedule for the fleet at yard (charging all vehicles together may exceed allotted load limit, also battery life is better if charged/discharged when cooled down)

Fleet analytics

Which models are performing as per manufacture promise, which one are not?
How to train drivers for optimal vehicle performance?

Analytics in EV Financing
Model battery end-of-life value

Predict battery life

Innovative models to reduce to make EV viable

EV has high upfront cost, and low operating and maintenance cost.
Battery usually amount to 30%-40% of the purchase cost.
How will the financing model look like if we sell vehicles, but lease batteries?

Model business use cases for logistics companies

EVs have much lower operating cost compared to ICE vehicles. So, better business case for fleet operations where kms per day is high.
What is the minimum kms commitment needed per day for EV to be profitable?

Warranty and Insurance

Modeling of warranty cost
Modeling of insurance cost

Analytics in EV Urban Planning

Where will the public chargers be needed (considering pattern of gasoline and electric charging needs are different)?

What will be the usage pattern (residential vs public)?


